# The computer has 48GB memory (or memories?)

Tags: grammatical-number

What's the correct form? If both are correct, what's the difference?

Comment: Quite simply it's "memory," and furthermore you must use "of" - just as with any quantity.  ("20 gallons of petrol,"  "200 baskets of wheat" etc. etc.)

Comment: So ... to take this further - did I write two lines of codes, two lines of code, two codes, or two code?

Comment: Incidentally, it's the convention with SI units (and so presumably non-SI units too) to always [leave a space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Writing_unit_symbols_and_the_values_of_quantities) between a value and its units, so I'd suggest doing the same here, i.e. 48 GB.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It would have to be 'memory', since computer memory is measurable, not countable.  In this particular case, 'memories' would be confusing as well as mistaken, since it would imply that the computer has several distinct memories, kept apart for some reason, and either each is 48GB capacity, or they total 48GB.  In my experience, the usual phrase is '48 GB *of* memory' , to avoid this problem.

Comment: +1 there are two memories: countable - something that you remember (childhood memories) and the other is uncountable - the ability to remember things (memory for names)

Comment: +1. But just to be a bit pedantic, a modern computer architecture actually does have several distinct memories used for different purposes. Registers, caches, and hard drive storage all serve a memory function. Nonetheless, it's understood that RAM is the only technical meaning of computer "memory".

Answer (score 6):

It is

> The computer has 48GB *of* memory.

*Memories* are the contents of one's *memory*, but I've never heard about contents of computer memory being called *memories*.

Comment: Probably because there are words which are more specific in this context, so *memories* would be unnecessarily vague metaphor (as opposed to *data*, *information*, *program*)

Answer (score 4):

That'd be 48 gigabytes of RAM, Random-Access Memory, not Memories.

I don't like it, but it looks like some vendors (Apple and HP) have started dropping Random Access:

http://www.apple.com/why-mac/compare/notebooks.html
http://www.shopping.hp.com/laptop

"2GB or 4GB memory"
"6GB memory"

Dell still spells it out for you:

http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-15r-combo-mod/pd?oc=fndor05&model_id=inspiron-15r-combo-mod

Memory
3GB3 Dual Channel DDR3 SDRAM at 1333MHz

Comment: "Memory" sounds less technical than RAM, but has the disadvantage of not distinguishing between RAM and hard disk space.

Comment: Regarding **dropping the 'of'**.  Your examples are simply not correct - they are taken from (totally non-grammatical) bullet-point lists.  Every single time Apple refers to memory in any normal prose, they say "of memory."  You can't omit the "of" when referring to a nondiscrete quantity: simple. (10 gallons of juice, 5 yards of cloth, etc.) The issue of omitting RA from RAM is a separate unrelated issue not germane to Cheng's question.

Comment: @Andrew - for 10 years at least, it has been very unusual to refer to drives as "memory."  Things like disk drives and SSD are just "storage" or "drives."  (Disk drives will be gone in a couple years, it is all SSD now.)  (Obviously "Hard" has been utterly redundant for what 15 yrs?!!) Memory means memory, live memory.  Amongst programmers "doing someting in memory" means specifically doing it live, in the memory, holding a calculation say all in memory all at once -- not using external storage.

Comment: Not all computer memory is RAM, it usually is these days, but your suggested replacement is not semantically equivalent. Luckily I don't have enough rep to down vote. *8')